# Can't run unit tests on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode7, ios9.2

I can't run unit tests on my iPhone. I need to run the unit tests on the phone because I need to access devices on the phone that the simulator cannot emulate. But every time I am get a breakpoint:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1200c1088)

The code highlighted at the breakpoint is:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x1200c1088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same problem. I am running from Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002).

Answer (score 3):

I experienced exactly the same symptoms. The tests ran on the simulator but not on device. In my case, the following were the steps to fix the problem:

1. Make sure that your main target has the `Team` selected in `Identity` option of the `General` target settings (it is not set to `None`:
   [image: Main Application Target Team Setting]
2. Then in the test target in the `Code Signing Identity` make sure it is not set to `Don't Code Sign`:

   BEFORE:

   [image: Test Target Code Signing Identity BEFORE]

   AFTER:

   [image: Test Target Code Signing Identity AFTER]

Comment: Why is there no "Don't Code Sign" in the AFTER image?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue

To fix it:

1. close Xcode
2. Clean (CMD+Shift+K)
3. Build (CMD+B)
4. try it

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just had similar issue.
What worked for me (Xcode 8 beta 6):

1. Disconnect device
2. Open DerivedData folder in Finder (Preferences->Locations)
3. Quit Xcode
4. Delete DerivedData folder
5. Restart Mac
6. Restart Device